# Is there a way to measure time wasted while waiting for MUTEX?

Tags: c++, windows, pthreads, mingw32

I know I can set a timer, but I have too many Mutex'es, all over the code.
I use windows 10, mingw32, pthreads and legacy c++ (but not c++11)

Comment: You could use timed mutexes.

Comment: To measure use a good profiling tool, that shows how many CPU cycles spent on each line of code.